# Antivirus which removes the CryptoLocker trojan

Tags: windows, antivirus

I am looking for antivirus working in windows (7/8/8.1/10) which is able to remove [Cryptographer virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoLocker) completely. Can you recommend an antivirus which kills this Trojan that encrypts the files?

Comment: ok, what do you mean by remove? Do your mean remove *just* the virus (even if your files are now encrypted) or unencrypt your files and remove the virus?

Comment: I mean a software that remove the Trojan which encrypt the files. Those encrypted files are gone, no way to have them back unless to pay!

Comment: Exactly, I'll add an answer now but it looks like [Avast](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index) may be able to [do the trick](https://blog.avast.com/2013/11/19/can-avast-protect-me-against-cryptolocker/)

Comment: At the time the computer get affected, avast was running on computer!!!

Comment: :/ Avast lied then

Comment: well,at the time that blog was written maybe it worked.

Comment: Sure, I don't know of if these tools will remove it but I've used these tools before and they're great, first try [Norton Power Eraser](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2013-091122-3112-99&tabid=3), [SuperAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/index.html), and this I use as my firewall and antivirus [Comodo Internet Security](https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php)

Comment: in the link you sent related to Symantec, it is written "Risk Level 1: Very Low" :-)

Comment: idk why they would say that but it should be a way to remove it regardless

Comment: If you already made peace with your files gone: Do a clean reinstall. The system is infected, your AV solution failed, in my opinion everything you do now will not result in a system I would still regard as compromised. Hopefully you had backups!

Comment: Given that files are gone and computer contains at least one professional malware it may be better to erase infected system and install from scratch. It gives higher chance that infection is really completely gone.

Comment: Many antivirus programs can remove this Trojan but are unable to decrypt your data. In some cases, users have re-installed the Trojan after removal in order to pay the ransom and unlock their data.

Answer (score 4):

According to Symantec, they have a product called Norton Power Eraser (NPE) that should be able to remove the Cryptolocker virus/trojan. For information provided by Symantec, see [this page](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2013-091122-3112-99&tabid=3). At the time of this writing, it was last updated on August 6, 2015, 3:39:36 PM.

You can download the latest version of this program from [this link](https://security.symantec.com/nbrt/npe.aspx).

## [Norton™ Power Eraser](https://security.symantec.com/nbrt/npe.aspx?lcid=1033)

> Is something not quite right with your computer? Are you being plagued by pop-up windows trying to get you to download security software or alerts claiming your PC isn’t secure? It sounds like you’ve been infected with a type of threat known as “scamware.” The solution? Norton Power Eraser.Norton Power Eraser is specially designed to aggressively target scamware. It uses our most thorough scanning technology to eliminate threats that traditional virus scanning doesn’t always detect, so you can get your PC back.
>
> [image: Norton Power Eraser UI]

Answer (score -2):

While not explicitly an AV solution, I've tried a few solutions and have settled on Rollback Rx. It's a solid program, it's recovered my PC on a handful of occasions from Cryptolocker or other malicious content.

The only downside is that the program needs to be installed on a clean system; it can't be used on a system with Cryptolocker. Still, in terms of performance and pure reliability in resolving the issue I think it's an easy choice.

Comment: The OP explicitly talks about a system already infected. That conflicts with the requirement *needs to be installed on a clean system*